# How to check if collection contains a value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-collection

I am unable to check whether following collection contains data or not

```
$users = \App\Tempuser::where('mobile','=',$request->mobile)->get();

if(isset($users))
  return "ok";
else
  return "failed";
```

but if there is nothing in `$users` still i am not getting else part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like `if ($users->count())` or `if (count($users))`.

Answer (score 4):

To check if the collection is empty you can use the [`isEmpty`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isempty) method:

```
if( $users->isEmpty() )
  return "collection is empty";
else
  return "collection is not empty";
```

Answer (score 2):

`->get()` will always return a collection, you just need to verify whether it contains elements.

```
if ($users->count())
    return "ok";
else
    return "failed";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro and put it into your AppServiceProvider

```
Collection::macro('assertContains', function($value) {
    Assert::assertTrue(
         $this->contains($value)
    );
});

Collection::macro('assertNotContains', function($value) {
    Assert::assertFalse(
        $this->contains($value)
    );
});
```